# What measure to use for small categorical judgements?

Tags: categorical-data, references, agreement-statistics

I have 3 to 5 (not sure yet) human judges that have to judge whether some photo's is similar to one of 4 known photo's. The outcome is a number between 1 and 4 (for a recognized photo) or zero for a photo unrecognized. For each unknown photo I would like to know:

- to what known photo the unknown photo looks like (that seems a matter
  of simple counting)
- a measure of agreement or deviation for each photo
- a measure of how much each judge agrees (or deviates) from the rest of the
  judges

I'm afraid this is basic knowledge for a statistician (which I am not) but I just do not know where to start. I'd be grateful for just a pointer to an article with some explanation.

Comment: How many unknown photos are there? Is the set of 4 known photos the same for all the unknown photos, or different? If different, is there any overlap between the several sets of 4 known photos, or are all sets disjoint?

Comment: The set of known photos is the same for all unknown photos. The known  photos are disjoint but very much look like each other. That's why we need several judges and a measure of interjudge reliability. The unknown photos belong to either one of the known categories or they are unknown.